# On Fourier-Bessel expansion

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, bessel-functions

Expand $f(x)=2$, $0<x<1$, in a Fourier-Bessel series using the Bessel function of order zero that satisfies the boundary condition $J_0(α)=0.$

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Please state what you have tried and where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about the kind of series you are looking for and the relevance of the boundary condition? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Vnk.png)

one of these I think

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.